# How would I use find to collect the paths of all directories, but not the paths of any subdirectories within the directories I want

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, find

I'm trying to collect the full pathways of every directory starting with the letter "K" in a large parent directory containing several hundred files and directories. Each of the directories also has subdirectories; the paths of which I don't want. I wanted to list all of my directory pathways in a file called samples.txt. My data is structured like this:

```
Parent_Directory
|
|__K1
|  |
|  |_Unnecessary_Directory1
|  |
|  |_Unnecessary_Directory2
|
|__K2
|  |
|  |_Unnecessary_Directory1
|  |
|  |_Unnecessary_Directory2
|
K3-K500, Several other unwanted directories/files
```

I have tried this command and was able to get a samples.txt file with only the paths of the K1-K500 files that I wanted, but I still get the unwanted paths of all of the subdirectories too.

```
find /Rest/of/Path/Parent_Directory/K* -type d > samples.txt
```

I tried using -prune as:

```
find /Rest/of/Path/Parent_Directory/K* -type d -prune -o -name 'Un*' > samples.txt
```

However, this just left me with an entirely blank samples.txt file. What edits should I make to give me only the K* directories, but not any subdirectories? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should achieve what you wanted :

```
find /Rest/of/Path/Parent_Directory/K* -type d -prune
```